# How to get the profile picture of my Gmail account?

Tags: ios, gmail, google-api

How can I access information from my Gmail account like photo, tokenId, first name, last name, and Gmail id?

I have searched a lot, but there is no proper answer.

Comment: Take a look at [Google Data APIs](https://developers.google.com/gdata/).  
[Retrieving a contact's photo](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#retrieving_a_contacts_photo)

Comment: It is programming question my friend.I just want to authenticate user via his/her gmail account and once user succesfully login, user can see his/her profile picture.

Comment: [The Google Data APIs Objective-C Client Library](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/)

Comment: Unfortunately i have not found any good code for that.I am stuck there my friend.Can you help me please?

Comment: @ParagBafna :i have checked that api my friend.But i cant find any method there to retrieve basic information of user.

Answer (score 0):

This api https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me returns

```
{
 "gender": "male",
 "id": "234343028403284",
 "displayName": "xxx",
 "name": {
    "familyName": "foo",
    "givenName": "bar"
   },
 "url": "https://plus.google.com/34324234324324",
 "image": {
  "url": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/dlkfjdsfds/djfldsf"
   }
 ...
 }
```

Before your application can get access to data from a user's Google Account, the application must request authorization from the user.

See https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth for information about oauth.

try: https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/ will help you understand oauth flow:

- Step 1: Select Google+, `Authorize apis`
- Step 2: `Exchange authorization code for tokens`
- Step 3: 
  enter https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me `Send the request`